# Can not generate greenDao Entity with lowercase

Tags: android, sqlite, assets, greendao, greendao-generator

I am using GreenDao library in my project and I have a problem when I want to read from DB, it gives me `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table`.

I know the reason why this happens. Its because when I generate the Scheme and add entity like this: `addEntity("userX")` the generated table is `USER_X`.

The problem is that I have loaded the db from assets and the table name is **`userX`**, not **`USER_X`**. I read in the [greendao doc](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/modelling-entities/) that: `For example, a property called “creationDate” will become a database column “CREATION_DATE”.`

My question is how can I change these defaults ?
I have searched in documentation for a solution but I havent found any solution. Is there a solution for my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used it, but looking at [this documentation](http://greendao-orm.com/javadoc/greendao-generator/) and [this source code](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/tree/master/DaoGenerator/src/de/greenrobot/daogenerator), it seems possible using this method for entities

```
Entity e = addEntity("userX");
e.setTableName("userX");
```

and this for properties

```
e.addDateProperty("creationDate").columnName("creationDate");
```